# Prove equivalence $((P \Rightarrow Q) \land (P \Rightarrow R)) \iff (P\Rightarrow(Q\land R))$

Tags: propositional-calculus

Prove equivalence $$((P \Rightarrow Q) \land (P \Rightarrow R)) \iff (P\Rightarrow(Q\land R))$$

What is the step by step for the equivalence of these equations. I can first break down the implications and use the distributive property, but then I get stuck.

Comment: Have you tried creating a truth table?

Comment: why don't you show what you've done, so we can help you get "unstuck"

Comment: Are you sure? If $P$ is true and $Q$ is false, then $(P\to Q)\land (P\to R)$ is false, but $(P\land Q)\to R$ is true.

Comment: Are you sure you do not mean $(q \Rightarrow r) \vee (p \Rightarrow r) \Leftrightarrow p \wedge q \Rightarrow r$?

Comment: Sorry, i miss wrote the question. I meant to write P=>(Q^R)

Comment: @user937897 See my second edit for the proof.

Comment: @user937897 You might want to edit your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

**EDIT**: *Given updated edit to question,* it seems we want to prove:

> $[P \rightarrow (Q\land R)] \iff [(P\rightarrow Q) \land (P\rightarrow R)]$
>
> It's usually best to prove $\iff$ equivalence-statements by *proving each direction of the double implication* $(\;\Rightarrow\;$ AND $\;\Leftarrow\;)$, so you don't make an *inadvertent mistake* by using a rule of inference that might go only one direction.

So you want to prove each of the following two implications:

> $$[(P\rightarrow Q) \land (P\rightarrow R)] \implies [(P \rightarrow (Q\land R)] \tag{1}$$
>
> $$[P\rightarrow (Q\land R)] \implies [(P \rightarrow Q) \land (P \rightarrow R)]\tag{2}$$

- Hints:
- for both (1) and (2): Use the identity that

  > $(A \rightarrow B) \equiv (\lnot A \lor B)\quad$ for each of the inner implications ($\rightarrow$).
- Then you can use *distribution*:

  > $[(A\lor B) \land C] \equiv [(A \land C) \lor (B \land C)];\quad[(A\land B) \lor C] \equiv [(A\lor C) \land (B \lor C)]$
- And use *DeMorgan's Laws*;

  > $\lnot (A \land B) \equiv (\lnot A \lor \lnot B),\quad \text{and} \quad \lnot (A \lor B) \equiv (\lnot A \land \lnot B)$
- Once you prove $(1)$, in this case you can prove $(2)$ by "undoing" what you did to prove $(1)$, starting with "undoing" the last step in the proof of $(1)$, and working backwards.

Note that each implication $(1)$ and $(2)$ is a tautology: both implications are true for all possible truth-value assignments to $P, Q, R$:

### [image]

Answer (score 1):

Let $P=1(true),Q=R=0(false)$, then $[(P\rightarrow Q) \land (P\rightarrow R)] \implies [(P \land Q) \rightarrow R]$ is true, but $[(P\land Q) \rightarrow R)] \implies [(P \rightarrow Q) \land (P \rightarrow R)]$ is not true. So the proposition is not true.

**You can also check *Wolframalpha*: [Link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28%28P%20IMPLIES%20Q%29AND%28P%20IMPLIES%20R%29%29%29IMPLIES%28%28P%20AND%20Q%29IMPLIES%20R%29AND%28%28P%20AND%20Q%29%20IMPLIES%20R%29%20IMPLIES%28%28%28P%20IMPLIES%20Q%29%20AND%20%28P%20IMPLIES%20R%29%29%29)**

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to show logical equivalence is to use truth tables.

**Edit**: I think you are trying to prove a false statement. If you mean $(q \Rightarrow r) \vee (p \Rightarrow r) \Leftrightarrow p \wedge q \Rightarrow r$, the proof is easy:
\begin{align}
(q \Rightarrow r) \vee (p \Rightarrow r) &\Leftrightarrow ({\sim} p \vee r) \vee ({\sim} q \vee r)\\
&\Leftrightarrow ({\sim}p \vee {\sim}q) \vee (r \vee r)\\
&\Leftrightarrow {\sim}(p \wedge q) \vee r\\
&\Leftrightarrow p \wedge q \Rightarrow r\\
\end{align}

**Edit**: The proof of $(p \Rightarrow q) \wedge (p \Rightarrow r) \Leftrightarrow p \Rightarrow (q \wedge r)$ is also easy:
\begin{align}
(p \Rightarrow q) \wedge (p \Rightarrow r) &\Leftrightarrow ({\sim}p \vee q) \wedge ({\sim}p \vee r)\\
&\Leftrightarrow (({\sim p}\vee q) \wedge {\sim}p) \vee (({\sim}p \vee q) \wedge r)\\
&\Leftrightarrow ({\sim}p) \vee (({\sim}p \wedge r) \vee (q \wedge r))\\
&\Leftrightarrow ({\sim}p) \vee ({\sim}p \wedge r) \vee (q \wedge r)\\
&\Leftrightarrow {\sim}p \vee (q \wedge r)\\
&\Leftrightarrow p \Rightarrow (q \wedge r)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Since you meant $P \rightarrow (Q \land R)$ instead of $(P \land Q) \rightarrow R$, according to your comment, then you can proceed as follows:

$$(P \rightarrow Q) \land (P \rightarrow R)$$
$$(\neg P \lor Q) \land (\neg P \lor R)$$
$$\neg P \lor (Q \land R)$$
$$P \rightarrow (Q \land R)$$

via the equivalence $P \rightarrow Q \leftrightarrow \neg P \lor Q$ and the distributive laws. For the converse, just reverse the above steps.